# My Django multiprocessing application can't use 100% of all cores

Tags: django, multithreading, python-2.7

I wrote the django application to tokenize a list of documents.I try to run it in parallel by using multiprocessing. But I found instead of all cores use 100% of its computation capability, it just take turns to let single one use up its 100% computation capability with other thread almost idle. I run a 4 cores 8 thread ubuntu 14.04 os, and python 2.7. Here I simplify my code to more easy to understand my code .

```
tokenization.py
def compute_customizedStopwords():
    stopword_dictionary = open(BASE_DIR + "/app1/NLP/Dictionary/humanDecisionDictionary.txt",'r')
    customizedStopwords = set()
    # compute stopwords set 
    for line in stopword_dictionary:
        customizedStopwords.add(line.strip('\n').lower()
    return customizedStopwords

def tokenize_task(narrative, customizedStopwords)
    tokens = narrative.corpus.split(",")
    tokens = [token for token in tokens if token not in customizedStopwords]  # remove stopwords
    newTokenObjects = [ Token(token = token) for token in tokens] 
    Token.objects.bulk_create(newTokenObjects) # save all tokens to database
    return tokens


views.py
def tokenize(request) :
    narratives = models.Narrative.objects.all() # get all documents 
    customizedStopwords = compute_customizedStopwords() # get stopwords set
    pool = Pool()
    results = [pool.apply(tokenize_task, args=(narrative, customizedStopwords)) for narrative in narratives]
    tokens = []
    tokens += results # flat the token list
    return HttpResponse(tokens)
```

Is it because the database write operation is the bottleneck, tokenization itself is very fast, but only one thread can write to databse and thus block all other threads? If this is the case, whether there is any ways to optimize this code?

I also has concerns about the stopwrods dictionary sets. I doubt python will copy this object for every job, and distribute them to every task. This will add memory cost especially I have 1 million documents in database.

Comment: One thing I need to add is that in my application, I also use scipy genism, and nltk. Are these module somewhere set the maximum thread as only 1.